# chromedriver SessionNotCreatedException

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've tried to scrape documents from a website, using `selenium` and `chromedriver`. I've updated chrome and chromedriver to current levels but am getting the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 128, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created exception
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.167)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.10.0-40-generic x86_64)
```

Are there suggestions for dealing with this error? The `SessionNotCreatedException` is resulting from a page timeout.

Answer (score 0):

The error does gives us some hint as follows :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created exception
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.167)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.10.0-40-generic x86_64)
```

A simple solution will be to pass the `Key` **executable_path** along with the `Value` of the absolute path of the *ChromeDriver* binary while initializing the *WebDriver* and *Web Browser* instance as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chromedriver_binary/chromedriver")
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Additionally ensure that you are using :

- The latest *JDK* version i.e. [*Java SE Development Kit 8u161*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
- The latest *Selenium Python Client* i.e. [*Selenium 3.9.0*](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium)
- Clean the *Project Space* from your *IDE* before and after your *Tests*.
- Run [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off the OS chores before and after executing your *Test Suite*.
- If the base version of *Chrome* is too old uninstall *Chrome* through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA released version of *Chrome*.
- Execute your *Tests*.

Comment: this suggestion did not fix the problem. selenium, chromedriver, and chrome are all updated to most recent versions.

how do i deal with the `SessionNotCreatedException`?